# Обновление даты обращения к файлу

Tags: c++, linux

Проблема такая: В Linux имеется файл с исходным кодом, точнее несколько файлов. Linux находится на виртуальной машине. Компилирую из консоли, при этом я меняю содержимое файла через winscp. После изменения файла, компилятор не видит изменений и след. не перекомпилирует сорци. Как я думаю, не модифицируется время изменения файла. Каким образом это можно поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touch <имя файла>` — изменит дату модификации.

Сделайте `stat <имя файла>` — увидите время модификации. Мне кажется, дело не в нём. Поскольку при копировании по scp скопированный файл получит mtime времени копирования.

Comment: Можно попробовать ключ scp -p чтобы явно заставить копировать даты изменений, etc